# Google API translation error: NotValidPayload in twitter dataset

Tags: python, google-translate

I **scraped** twitter data and tried to translate the whole dataset (around 30.000) with deeptranslator from googletrans in Python. To overcome the api limit, I subdivided the dataset in smaller batches. But there is still a problem, probably with the nan values in user_description? Could someone help out?

```
batch_1 = no_eng_data.iloc[0:1000]
batch_2 = no_eng_data.iloc[1000:2000]

def batch_translation(batch):
    data_list = []
    for index, row in batch.iterrows():
        if row["user_description"] != row["user_description"]:
            text = ""
        else:
            text = row["user_description"]
        #text = row['user_description']
        translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(text=text)
    
        data_list.append(translated)
    
    return data_list

data_list_1 = batch_translation(batch_1)
with open('data_list_1.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data_list_1, f)
time.sleep(300)

error: NotValidPayload:  --> text must be a valid text with maximum 5000 character, 
otherwise it cannot be translated ´´´
```